# Output Chart for the performance of a query in asp.net

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm doing a project in ASP.Net in which I'm using lots of queries.

I have completed the project but according to the customer requirement I have to provide a chart for the performance of each and every query.

The query that I have used throughout is for reducing the redundancy of values during the output.

Now for the performance I'm thinking to use MS chart.

But I guess Crystal Reports can also be used. If Crystal Reports can be used then how??

Comment: As a general rule I don't respond to questions with links to google - but in this case, this appears to be a request for tutorials on graphing in Crystal. In which case, I suggest: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=tutorial+graphing+"crystal+reports"

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide data for a ms-chart component then you can provide them even to a Crystal Report. I think (but it's just an opinion) you'll get even more benefits to use a standard reporting component, your users will be able to export that data, you'll have a consistent interface and you won't need to change any application code when you'll add a new query/report (I guess now you're using CR to provide an output for your queries).

Comment: can u be a little more specific. I  want to know how it can be implemented using the crystal reports. Any hints please.

Comment: It depends on where your performance data come from. Do you have another query to provide that data? Are you using Microsoft SQL Server and its query performance tools?

Comment: Yeah im using MS SQL server as its backend. Everything works fine apart from the Chart. Can u provide any idea for using the crystal reports. I havent used them so far.

Comment: Also is it possible to comapre two queries using crystal reports

Comment: Ok, then I have to refine my answer! If you're not using CR maybe you do not really need to pull it inside your application just to provide few charts output...
Anyway you may start from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500296.aspx, if you want to use CR you may put CR report viewer control into your page and then fetch data from sql server.